# How to create a strongswan VPN connection in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, networkmanager, vpn, strongswan

The drop down in

- Edit connections... -> Add -> choose connection type

of the network-manager only shows the Point-to-Point Tunneling Protocol (PPTP) although strongswan VPN is installed. Why and what can I do to enable the IPsec option?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the `network-manager-strongswan` package as well. But note that the package seems quite buggy and I'm not sure it's still working well.

Answer (score 0):

there is a bug in the plugin NetworkManager-strongswan < 1.4.0, see https://wiki.strongswan.org/issues/1429

to enable the option, download NetworkManager-strongswan >= 1.4.0 and compile from source, see https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2327303

steps:

```
# possibly required packages for network-manager strongswan plugin
sudo apt-get install build-essential libgtk-3-dev
sudo apt-get install libsecret-1-dev
sudo apt-get install libnm-glib-vpn-dev
sudo apt-get install libnm-gtk-dev
sudo apt-get install libnma-dev

# get the NetworkManager strongsSwan plugin as a tarball
wget http://download.strongswan.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager-strongswan-1.4.2.tar.bz2
tar xjf NetworkManager-strongswan-1.4.2.tar.bz2
cd NetworkManager-strongswan-1.4.2

# build the NetworkManager strongsSwan plugin
./configure -sysconfdir=/etc -prefix=/usr -with-charon=/usr/lib/ipsec/charon-nm

# build
make
make install
```

Comment: `network-manager-strongswan` package version 1.4.2 is already in debian/ubuntu

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and it had version 1.3.1 installed: "network-manager-strongswan is already the newest version (1.3.1-1ubuntu1)."

Comment: MMh OK the LTS version has still an old version, more recent ubuntu releases have a newer one: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-strongswan